# "Would you like to get something to eat together?"

Tags: dates

A guy who I went out for a coffee once just asked me "would you like to get something to eat together?" I said sounds good but started to wonder if he meant "we go to a restaurant to have dinner" or "we get takeout then go back to his place." Usually guys would just say "would you like to go out for dinner" or "would you like to grab dinner." if they mean dining out. I wanted to ask him to clarify it but felt kinda silly. I don't wanna go if he meant takeout.

Anyway he's a native speaker while I'm not. I'm wondering if anyone can clarify it for me. Bear with me if this sounds silly lol. Thank you!

Comment: This is an invitation to go out for a meal at a restaurant, not to pick up take-out. It could be lunch or dinner.

Answer (score 2):

It suggests some kind of restaurant, but nothing very fancy. But it could be takeout or street food. Or it could even be getting something from the shops to cook at home. Only he knows for sure. So ask *him*.

There's nothing odd in asking for clarification.  This is what a native speaker would do in the same situation: "Sounds good, do you mean like a restaurant?" Having a conversation to clarify meaning is normal. You can be more direct: "Sounds good, but not takeout, let's go to a restaurant."